# Replacing React in the MERN stack with React Native for developing a mobile application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, express

I started to learn MERN Stack (MongoDB, Express, React, Node.js) for web development... My question is can I use the same but replacing React with React Native (MongoDB, Express, React Native, Node.js) to develop a mobile application?

Comment: Yes it is possible to do that! Creating a REST API with Express that communicates with your MongoDB and React Native frontend is perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is possible! You write your backend using Express and MongoDB just like you would when creating a Web-App. You just have to switch from "pure" REACT to REACT Native. And REACT Native is a perfectly fine choice if you're already familiar with REACT.